# The resolution option is greyed out when duplicating display with monitor and projector

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 7 PC which has an built-in Intel graphics card and one NVIDIA Quadro 410 graphics card.
A monitor and a projector are connected to the PC.

When I duplicate the monitor display with the projector, the resolution option is greyed out.
If I change the resolution just for the monitor, then it is working.
If I change the resolution just for the projector, then it is greyed out.

How do I get the resolution option enabled when duplicating my display across the monitor and the projector?

Comment: I was unable to figure out the actual cause of the issue but got a workaround to fix the issue and make the system work accordingly. I uninstalled the updated NVIDIA driver and installed back the old driver of 2014, which made the system work. was able to change the screen resolution. It seems the latest driver was not compatible with the PC projector.